# Order date showing 01-01-1970 in WooCommerce orders when exported to ShipStation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, feed

So there's an interesting problem going on with our store. We've had no problems up until now, but the since the latest WooCommerce update, all the order dates exported via the WooCommerce order feeds to ShipStation are showing 01-01-1970. I was able to confirm that this is not a ShipStation issue, but a WooCommerce one.

I checked all the data tables in our MySQL database (because I originally thought it could be a MySQL database issue), but everything seems fine.

The order date shows as follows:

```
<OrderDate>01/01/1970 07:00</OrderDate>
```

However, the Last Modified shows the correct date/time:

```
<LastModified>05/23/2018 15:42</LastModified>
```

Anyone else know what could be causing it?

Comment: As stated in my original post, I have confirmed that it is not a ShipStation issue, but rather an issue related to WooCommerce. The RSS feed for WooCommerce orders is exporting the order date as shown above instead of the current date.

Comment: Anyway, your question is not directly related to programing as defined in StackOverFlow scope. If it's a WooCommerce issue due to last update, you should report it to Woocommerce directly. The very new version 3.4 comes with bugs as always and they will be solved in next updates.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else has this issue, I found an odd fix:

WordPress Settings > change Local Time Zone to something other than what it was before > Hit Save > Change Local Time Zone back to your original Time Zone > Hit Save.

Now orders are showing the correct date and time.